# Can more USB 2 devices go on a USB 3 port?

Tags: usb

I understand that the data rate of a USB devices remains the same whether it is on a controller that's its own version, or higher.  But is the total aggregate bandwidth higher when using USB 2 devices on a USB 3 controller?  E.g. can I have more USB 2 devices running on a USB controller at the same time, than I could on a USB 2 controller?

Edit: I am talking about throughput, not the maximum number of devices.  I am maxing out a USB 2 controller (not number of devices, throughput.)  I am wondering if moving my devices over to a USB 3 controller will help.

Comment: FYI, I voted to move this over to SuperUser, as this is a power user / client facing question just about no matter how you slice it. People on serverfault are really more into servers that run in active business environments.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will make no difference. USB2 devices can't talk at USB3 speeds, regardless of the controller version. So when a controller port is talking to a USB2 device, it can't talk at USB3 speeds either. It doesn't even use the USB3 wires.

The only way a faster controller would make any difference is if it had more ports and thus devices that were previously connected to the same controller port were changed to connect to different controller ports.

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation from the downvoter.